# Несколько вариантов в CheckBox Pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Как выбрать несколько `checkbox` если используется их группировка через `QButtonGroup`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Тест'
        self.resize(400, 400)

        self.setFont(QFont('Times', 13))
        layout =QVBoxLayout()
        radiobox = QCheckBox('Ответ 1',self)
        radiobox2 = QCheckBox('Ответ 2', self)
        self.button_group = QButtonGroup()
        self.button_group.addButton(radiobox, 1)
        self.button_group.addButton(radiobox2, 2)
        self.button_group.buttonClicked.connect(self.selectedchoice)
        layout.addSpacing(20)
        layout.addWidget(radiobox)
        layout.addSpacing(20)
        layout.addWidget(radiobox2)
        layout.addStretch(1)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

    def selectedchoice(self, butt):
        print(self.button_group.id(butt))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Есть вариант просто к каждому `checkbox` сделать `clicked.connect`, но как мне кажется что можно как нибудь сделать по `id` как и с `QButtonGroup`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Тест'
        self.resize(400, 400)

        self.setFont(QFont('Times', 13))
        layout =QVBoxLayout()
        self.radiobox = QCheckBox('Ответ 1',self)
        self.radiobox.clicked.connect(self.selected_choice_1)
        self.radiobox2 = QCheckBox('Ответ 2', self)
        self.radiobox2.clicked.connect(self.selected_choice_2)
        layout.addSpacing(20)
        layout.addWidget(self.radiobox)
        layout.addSpacing(20)
        layout.addWidget(self.radiobox2)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

    def selected_choice_1(self, state):
        if state :
            print(self.radiobox.text())
    def selected_choice_2(self, state):
        if state :
            print(self.radiobox2.text())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что то похожее на `QButtonGroup`, но привязанная к кнопке

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Тест'
        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.setFont(QFont('Times', 13))
        layout =QVBoxLayout()
        self.radiobox = QCheckBox('Ответ 1',self)
        self.radiobox2 = QCheckBox('Ответ 2', self)
        layout.addSpacing(20)
        layout.addWidget(self.radiobox)
        layout.addSpacing(20)
        layout.addWidget(self.radiobox2)
        push = QPushButton()
        push.clicked.connect(self.selected_choice_1)
        layout.addWidget(push)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

    def selected_choice_1(self):
        if self.radiobox.isChecked():
            print(self.radiobox.text())
        if self.radiobox2.isChecked():
            print(self.radiobox2.text())



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Похожий вопрос был на Английском stackoverflow [Using a checkbox in pyqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462078/using-a-checkbox-in-pyqt)   и [How to check if a checkbox is checked in pyqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20455499/how-to-check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-pyqt?noredirect=1&lq=1)